# Два слайдера с одной навигацией

Tags: javascript, html

Два слайдера которые работаю синхронно. Нашел решение: http://www.bootply.com/Jxk1uu3WlN - тут первых два слайдера работаю вместе!
Однако хочу еще сделать чтобы они переключались синхронно по маркерам. Добавил маркеры, но не знаю что делать дальше. Попробовал сделать точно так же как с обычными переключателями, но ничего не вышло. Кто знает выход из этой ситуации?

Comment: маркеры внизу обращаются только к первой карусели, т.к. используют айди: `<li data-target="#carousel-a"...`, а у соседних каруселей айди другой. решение зависит от того, как вам удобнее. можно скриптом прописать зависимость остальных слайдов от первого, можно скриптом указать переключение по маркеру соседним слайдерам...

Comment: @lexxl каким образом можно прописать зависимость остальных слайдов от первого?

Answer (score 2):

Получилось сделать. Ниже решение, кому нужно будет.

Для маркеров добавил класс ".nav".

И потом в JS изменил код с этого:

```
$('.carousel-sync').carousel('cycle');
$('.carousel-sync').on('click', '.carousel-control[data-slide]', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $('.carousel-sync').carousel($(this).data('slide'));
});
```

На этот:

```
$('.carousel-sync').carousel('cycle');
$('.carousel-sync').on('click', '.nav[data-slide-to]', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $('.carousel-sync').carousel($(this).data('slide-to'));
});
```